# Письма с формы заявки приходят в одну цепочку

Tags: php, email, form, форма

Есть форма заявки с лендинга, и письма приходят в одну цепочку. Начинается следующий день, первая заявка приходит новым письмом, все остальные опять начинают попадать в эту же цепочку. Письма приходят на gmail ящик. Отправляю mail php, почтой созданной на хостинге. По инструкциям от хостинга.

В каждой форме стоят такие идентификаторы.

```
<input type="hidden" name="project_name" value="Заявка с лендинга">
<input type="hidden" name="admin_email" value="мойимейл@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="Форма главный экран">
```

Вот сам php отправки

```
<?php

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

//Script Foreach
$c = true;
if ( $method === 'POST' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_POST["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_POST["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_POST["form_subject"]);

    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
} else if ( $method === 'GET' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_GET["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_GET["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_GET["form_subject"]);

    foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
}

$message = "<table style='width: 100%;'>$message</table>";

mail($admin_email, $form_subject, $message, "From: $project_name <opt@grade-coffee.com>" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: opt@grade-coffee.com" . "\r\n" . "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . "\r\n" . "Content-type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"");
```

Comment: В одну цепочту это когда открываешь письмо в таблице, а под ним куча писем, как и на Яндексе? Все письма приходит на один и тот же адрес? Вроде так и должно быть же.

Comment: Да, куча писем в одном. Нужно каждое письмо отдельным сообщением. До этого когда отправлял со своей почты ( а не с хостинговой) на свою же. Все приходило отдельными письмами, но часто в спам попадает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А чего вы хотите добиться? Гугл сортирует цепочки по теме письма:

> Цепочки писем: (определяет, будут ли группироваться сообщения
>   электронной почты, связанные одной темой)

У вас в hidden стоит одна тема

```html
<input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="Форма главный экран">
```

Соответственно все письма будут собираться. Если хотите делить, то можно добавлять в тему дату и время или уникальный код,

```
uniqid();
```

тогда каждое письмо будет индивидуальным, либо отключить цепочки писем в Гугл.

Comment: а как добавить правильно uniqid(); и куда? подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: например сюда > $form_subject = trim($_POST["form_subject"])." №".uniqid();

Comment: спасибо, все работает. В тему письма добавляется рандомный номер с буквами и цифрами. Было бы круто сделать чтоб происходил порядковый отчет. Типа №1, след. заявке №2 и тд. Можно как-то такое реализовать?)

Comment: Да, такое тоже можно сделать - нужно будет сделать свой счетчик писем - например, как описан здесь http://coderhs.com/archive/easy_count_php - только считаете количество заполненных форм